# aws iot-data --generate-cli-skeleton output is invalid

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-iot

I run next command in bash:

`aws --endpoint-url https://xxxxxx.iot.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com --profile iot iot-data publish --topic "sdk/test/java" --payload "1" --qos 1 --generate-cli-skeleton`

and get output:

```
{
    "topic": "",
    "qos": 0,
    "payload": null
}
```

So, it looks like an invalid json because I expected to have there something like this:

```
{
    "topic": "sdk/test/java",
    "qos": 1,
    "payload": 1
}
```

Comment: It sends the payload without problems as is. I thought that publishing didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [generate-cli-skeleton](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/generate-cli-skeleton.html) switch in the AWS CLI will only produce a json document with all of the possible parameters for that comment, but it will not insert values based on your cli command.

It will simply return a valid json document that you can edit afterwards and then feed to `cli-input-json` parameter of the CLI command.